# My Splash Screen won't move on?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am currently trying to flash a three second Splash Screen before moving on to the first activity. However, once the splash screen shows up, it doesn't move on to the next "Main Menu" Screen.

```
package edu.wcu.lect4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

final int PAUSE = 3000;
Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

}


protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();

      handler = new Handler();
      handler.postDelayed(r, PAUSE);
}//end on start}
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
         goToNextScreen();
         finish();
    }
};

private void goToNextScreen()
{
    Intent menu = new Intent(this, edu.wcu.lect4.MainMenu.class);
    this.startActivity(menu);
}
```

}

Also, here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splashscrn"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainMenu" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Press me" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="MAIN MENU" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running through the debugger and stepping through it?

Comment: Yes, and the code compiles and runs fine... the only complaint i'm getting is a warning stating that "android.view.Menu isn't used"

Comment: [**Splash Screens Are Evil, Don't Use Them!**](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're starting the same activity over and over again. Intent from the `goToNextScreen()` method should start Activity other than `MainMenu`. But please consider Alex's comment. Using splash screens is not recommended.